# Why does the definition of ionisation energy only include gaseous atoms?

Tags: electrons, energy, ionization-energy

I know that in physics there is thermionic emission and the photoelectric effect. These are both method of removing electrons. I think these affects are only for metals due to their de-localized electrons.

So why do they say that you can remove the valence electron of a gaseous atom? Can you not do this with atoms in their solid or liquid state, and does being a metal, non metal or metalloid affect this?

Comment: Thermionic emission and the photoelectric effect are applicable to all materials. While these indeed remove an electron from the material, and the energies at which that happens are very interesting, the energies are fundamentally tied to condensed phases with band structures, not to single atomic energy levels.